# Write three columns of file to new text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I am reading data from a big .gtf file. Here is the code for it:

```
fname="gencode.v19.annotation.gtf"


for line in open(fname,'r'):
    if not line.startswith('##'):
        col1=line.split()[0]
        col3=line.split()[2]
        col4=line.split()[3]
        col5=line.split()[4]
        if "protein_coding" in line and col3=="exon":
            data = col1,col4,col5
            results=list(data)
            print(results)


dataFile = open('results.txt','w')

for list in results:
    dataFile.writelines(results)

dataFile.close()
```

The results that print out in IDLE look like this:

```
['chr1', '120461029', '120461176']
['chr1', '120460288', '120460385']
['chr1', '120454176', '120459317']
['chr1', '120466260', '120466528']
['chr1', '120465118', '120465401']
['chr1', '120479905', '120480086']
['chr1', '120477890', '120478227']
['chr1', '120611948', '120612240']
['chr1', '120547952', '120548211']
```

(but there are a TON of them....)

My question is, why is my current code not working to print all my data into the new text file? How should I write the code so that it doesn't print the whole thing first and THEN import it to the new file? How can I have it import to the new text file automatically?

Any help at all would be EXTREMELY appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep reassigning `results` in the for loop so it only has the final bit of data when you get around to writing the file. You probably want to create results as a list and append the data as you go.

```
fname="gencode.v19.annotation.gtf"

results = []
for line in open(fname,'r'):
    if not line.startswith('##'):
        col1=line.split()[0]
        col3=line.split()[2]
        col4=line.split()[3]
        col5=line.split()[4]
        if "protein_coding" in line and col3=="exon":
            data = col1,col4,col5
            results.append(data)
            print(data)

with open('results.txt','w') as datafile:
    for data in results:
        dataFile.write(str(data)) # Fix this: I dont know what formatting you want
```

Or, do the writing in the for loop:

```
fname="gencode.v19.annotation.gtf"
with open('results.txt','w') as datafile:

    results = []
    for line in open(fname,'r'):
        if not line.startswith('##'):
            col1=line.split()[0]
            col3=line.split()[2]
            col4=line.split()[3]
            col5=line.split()[4]
            if "protein_coding" in line and col3=="exon":
                data = col1,col4,col5
                dataFile.write(str(data)) # Fix this: I dont know what formatting you want
                print(data)
```

Comment: thank you SO MUCH. This has worked! Thank you x10000

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having the results printed, comment the print function:

```
#print(results)
```

Then, there is a problem with your write-to-file code snippet:

```
for list in results:
    dataFile.writelines(results)
```

writelines() expects a list of strings, you do not have to iterate over your list of string (results) yourself.

Either use write() AND iterate:

```
for line in results:
    dataFile.write(line)
```

or use writelines correctly:

```
dataFile.writelines(results)
```

Comment: thanks, however none of the data is getting written to my new file so i don't know what else is wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

The code now is only writing out the last assignment to `results`.  You need to write (or append) to the output file through each iteration of the loop.  Or, you can separate the read and write portions of the code by initializing an empty array to store all `results` through the for loop.

Few more suggestions:

a) avoid using the variable name `list`, as that's a protected word in Python.

b) Use the `with` syntax for file opening, since this will automatically close the file when its usage ends.

c) I would `split` the line once, then assign variable names in one line.

```
with open('./results.txt', 'w') as outfile:
   with open('./gencode.v19.annotation.gtf', 'r') as infile:
       for line in infile:
           col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = line.split()
           if 'protein_coding' in line and col3=='exon':
                outfile.write(','.join([col1, col4, col5]))
```